# Slow query on large table with 50M plus data (especially with larger offset)

Tags: sql-server

**Scenario**

I have a table with 50M plus data.

I need to fetch 4 columns and show on datatable order by 'name_voter' column.

First, I started with basic query such as

```
 select id,name_voter,home_street_address_1, home_address_city
from base_voter 
where deleted_at is null
order by home_street_address_1
offset @pagesize * (@pagenumber - 1) rows
fetch next @pagesize rows only option(recompile)
```

With the increase in data, it started to become slow. So, I decided to create an index as

```
create index IX_base_voter_name_voter_asc_deleted_at on base_voter(name_voter asc,deleted_at) include(home_street_address_1, home_address_city) where deleted_at is null
```

It makes quite faster but not enough, so one of my friends suggest to create additional table as:

```
create table base_voter_name_voter
(
sr_no bigint not null,
base_voter_id int,
constraint pk_name_voter_sr_no primary key (sr_no)
)
go
```

and need to run following query on every insertion/deletion in the base_voter table

```
create procedure procUpdateSortDetails
as
begin
    truncate table base_voter_name_voter
    insert into base_voter_name_voter(sr_no,base_voter_id)
    select row_number() over(order by name_voter asc),id from base_voter with(nolock)
    where deleted_at is null
end
go
```

After this the execution time is acceptable, but still, I am not convinced to run that query on every update.

**My question:**

1) Is there any other way to make this faster without updating this additional table on every insertion manually need to be automatically updated something as in index.

2) Isn't index itself should be enough to handle tasks like this? Am I doing it incorrectly or only this much index is capable

3) Is any other way to deal with such problems, to make the query faster even for the last page?

4) If there is also some other way of representing data so that this query might not be needed. Please, mention those.

My data table is something like

---

name_voter (asc)     |     home_street_address_1    |    home_address_city

---

Please, suggest some way to tackle this problem.

Comment: Not directly related, but you must append the key column (Id) in your sort as a tie breaker in case two rows have the same home_street_address_1.  Otherwise you could get missing and duplicated rows across pages.

Answer (score 2):

Try this index:

```
create index IX_base_voter_home_street_address_1_asc
on base_voter(home_street_address_1 asc)
include(id, name_voter, home_address_city, deleted_at)
where deleted_at is null
```

Comment: still taking a lot of time around 20 sec

Comment: Yes,@SarojShrestha , this index is better than previous one.i don't know why you mark it answer in your "delete question."Can you say what data type is home_street_address_1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Truncating and inserting data in  `base_voter_name_voter` is really very bad bad idea.

Instead create `History Table` of base_voter.
Create `Update Trigger` on  `base_voter`.
Delete the rows from base_voter and insert the deleted rows in History table.

Therefore no need of `Filtered index` on Base_voter .Also base_voter will hold less records.

and your index become,

```
create index IX_base_voter_home_street_address_1_asc
on base_voter(home_street_address_1 asc)
include(id, name_voter, home_address_city, deleted_at)
```

So same query with this index will be far far better.

IMO,this is best way of soft deleting data.